# FloatingActionButton scrolls down as the user scrolls down or adds new views

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently working on a University app where 1 UI thread is responsible for adding the semester buttons.  When the app rotates and the FloatingActionButton is clicked to add views, the button scrolls down with them at each click after the views have went below the screen.  I tried to tweak my XML but nothing happened unfortunately.  My question is how can I maintain my FAB at the same position on the screen when the user scrolls up and down?

This is my UI thread:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counter = 0;

    FloatingActionButton addingSemester;
    Button semesterButton;
    LinearLayout semesterLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addingSemester = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);
        semesterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.delete) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Delete entry")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            semesterLayout.removeAllViews();
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        if (counter < 8) {
            semesterButton.setId(counter + 1);
            semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (counter + 1));
            semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            lp.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);
            semesterButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
            semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
            counter++;
            semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    final Button b = (Button) v;
                    b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
                    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    b.setText("Delete");

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Delete entry")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeView(b);
                                    counter--;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < semesterLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        ((Button) semesterLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    b.cancelLongPress();
                                    b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                    b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

        } else if (counter == 8) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context="myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dp">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:onClick="onFloatActionButtonClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="com.myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.ScrollingFABBehavior"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Sorry.  I just edited it.